# Android alternatives resources for 5.5'' and 6'' phones

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to know how can I add alternative resource for android devices with 5.5'' and 6' within a project structure. 
I want to add a custom dimens.xml file with different text sizes for devices between 5.5 and 6 inches.
I was thinking to use the small width configuration qualifiers but there is so many screen configuration that I do not know which screen size would be the smallest width for 5.5'' and 6'' phones. The other alternative that I can use is the screen size buckets (small, normal, large, xlager) but those are deprecative from android 3.2 and above.

Can someone advice me about this?.

Comment: Different text sizes in dimens.xml is recommended. Have you implemented that?

Comment: You should never target screen dimensions in inch with your resources? What if two 6" inch phones have completely different pixel densities? Then your assets would look completely different on those two devices. The only value you should care about is dp. And you should use the buckets recommended by Google to create optimal user interfaces across all devices.

Answer (score 3):

I appreciate your advice, but look this example.

I have this phone:
- Nexus 5x with 5.2’’  resolution 1080x1920 px, 420dpi

```
dp = px / (dpi / 160) 
dp = 1080 px /  (420 dpi / 160)
dp = 411 dp
```

- Nexus 6p with 5.7 resolution 1440x2560 px, 560dpi

  dp = px / (dpi / 160)

  dp = 1440 px / (560 dpi / 160)

  dp = 411 dp

if I create a specific set of resources just for the Nexus 6p with 5.7’’, or for devices with just 5.7’’ I could crate this folder

```
values-sw411dp
```

But all the resources within that folder will be used when the app is used on both devices 5.2’’ and 5.7’’.

I have other problem, it may be that smallest phones like, 5.0’’ could have biggest dp than the 5.7’’, what its going to happen is that the resources for the 5.7’’ device  it will be used for the 5.0’’ devices too.

How can I specify resource just for 5.7’’ phones.

Comment: I see your point, however the images should look well on both devices if the dp sizes are the same. What is the problem you experience when using the same image for phones having the same dp size?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are right I'd also go with the smallest-width buckets.

You can calculate the smallest width, by checking the phones dimensions in `dp`, with the formula given in [the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

```
px = dp * (dpi / 160)
```

So to get the smallest width dp:

```
dp = px / (dpi / 160)
```

Where `px` is the pixels on the smaller dimension, `dpi` is the dot per inch ratio of the device.
So first check the devices' pixel size and `dpi` value, then calculate the `dp` value with the formula above. Then you can create the folder with the resources like `sw400dp` where you can change  to the calculated `dp`.

Also I'd suggest to check for other device dimensions to not have weird layouts on smaller / larger screens.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your advice, but look this example.

Answer (score 1):

Abbath, thank you very mucho keep answering my questions. I am not working with images, I am working with the text size of a TextView. I need to change the textView text size, only if the devices screen size is bigger than 5.5''. I created a `/value-sw411dp/dimens.xml` which contain the corresponding textview text size. I found that `sw411dp` is the smallest dp width of the 5.5'' devices, but there is an other phone that has 5.2'' that has the same screen spaces. So, the system will used the resources within the `/values-sw411dp/` for devices with 5.5''and 5.2''.

What you where telling me is that if a 5.2'' has the same screen dp as a 5.5'', I shouldn't worried about that because at the end the UI layout will look the same without problems.